# Apache, Ruby, no framework

Tags: ruby, apache

What is the best way to run Ruby scripts using Apache and no framework (just like PHP scripts)?

Bonus points if the script can access the HTTP request stuff (URL, host, GET/POST params and cookie). If a framework is absolutely required, which is the most lightweight which would use Apache?

Comment: You can launch any Ruby http-server you like and tune Apache to redirect requests to it using mod_rewrite. http://www.google.com/search?q=apache+mod+rewrite and http://web.archive.org/web/20071010213134/www.ilovejackdaniels.com/mod_rewrite_cheat_sheet.png

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Apache with `mod_rack` and the [Rack interface](http://rack.rubyforge.org/) to communicate with the server.

Comment: I always wondered how rails, sinatra & co. handles requests and his flow? I never understood it. In php there is the famous "index.php"

Answer (score 1):

Try [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) and you can write something like this:

```
require 'sinatra'
get '/hi' do
  "Hello World!"
end
```

It is actually a framework, but the smallest application on Sinatra is MUCH smaller than smallest application on Rails.